# Getting error while trying to get the document id

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

IM trying to get the Document id of data in flutter. But im getting this error :

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
Class 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docId'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: docId

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      Messages.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:project/seitenleiste/nachrichten.dart:425:50)
#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:455:22)
#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1213:28)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1226:55)

====================================================================================================
```

IM using the for not getting errors while firebase update my widget .
Hope anyone can help if you need more code leave a comment .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a few months the document ID is called `id` instead of `docId`.

I highly recommend keeping the reference documentation for the plugin handy while developing, as it's quite easy to find this sort of problem in the documentation for [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html).

Comment: Yes thank you you solved it and thanks for the tip.